# I need a generic word for product and subscription service for an e-commerce site

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

The site I am designing the data schema for will be

- selling subscription service and
- selling access to certain features for a one time fee.

I can call the latter a **"*product*"** and then I need a word for what combines both subscription and product, or I can use ***product*** as a generic word that combines subscription and the things I sell for one time fee, but then I need a word for that latter thing.

UPDATE: I decided on using "service" and "product" as the types of stuff I offer on the site, but the top level, the generic name that combines both, is still in question. "Offering" suggested by @BiscuitBoy is quite close but it doesn't feel like the right terminology - I need something a bit more e-commerce'y :)

Comment: Please define "e-commerce-y". You yourself imply *offering* with 'I decided on using "service" and "product" as the types of stuff I **offer** on the site'. What are criteria you are using to judge suggestions? ELU is not a guessing-game.

Answer (score 2):

I feel an **offering** would best fit your description

***[offering](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/offering)***

> (noun) something offered for sale or patronage

[Merriam-Webster]

**Usage**:

The e-com site has a few ***offerings***, including subscription services and access to special/Pro features for an one-time fee